# Getting remote URL for a Git repo

Tags: git, scripting

Background: I'm developing a (FreePascal :) ) updater tool in FreePascal. 1 of the functionalities is downloading/updating source code from remote hg, svn and git repositories. Git newb. Added scripting etc tags because I'm calling git commands, not using libraries.

How do I get the remote URL for a directory with a git repo?
doing
git ls-remote -h seems to output
From git://gitorious.org/fg/fgdata
to stderr and a lot of other data

I'm just interested in the
git://gitorious.org/fg/fgdata
part.

Is there an easier (read: supported by git plumbing) way of getting this than parsing the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the initial remote repo is stored as `origin` if not explicitly specified. Assuming your remote repo's name has not been changed, this should show the URL for the remote repo `origin`:

```
git config remote.origin.url
```